# How to add a item at the last in the list by recursion?

Tags: java, list, recursion

```java
public class SLList {

    public class IntNode {
        public int item;
        public IntNode next;
        public IntNode(int i, IntNode n){
            item = i;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    public IntNode first;

    public SLList(int x){
        first = new IntNode(x,null);
    }

    public void addFirst(int x){
        first = new IntNode(x, first);
    }

    public int getfirst(){
        return first.item;
    }
    
    public void addLast(int x) {
    
    }
    
    public static void  main(String[] args){
        SLList L =  new SLList(10);
        L.addFirst(5);
        L.addFirst(8);
        L.addLast(9);
        System.out.println(L.getfirst());
    }
}
```

How to add an item at the last in the list using recursion? I want to add the last of the list by recursion but am not able to do so as I go through the pointer is pointing at the last element so it's returning the element added and the last element and not the whole list.

Comment: I don't think you even need recursion for this. Just keep a reference to the last item and update it on `addLast()`

Comment: yeah @Charles I done it iteratively but I just wanted to know how do it by recurison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing a recursive method you need to implement two parts:

- **base case** that represents an input for which it's clear the expected output will be. In your case, the *last node* is a node that doesn't point to any other node, i.e. its `next` field is `null`. Also as a precaution, we need to address the situation when the *given node* is `null` before accessing its `next` field.
- **recursive case** - is a part recursive calls happen and main logic of the method resides. For this task, the *recursive case* is fairly simple: if the *current node* isn't `null` and it points to the *non-null* node, then the *next* node should be returned.

In order to add a *new last node* firstly we need to find a reference to the existing one.

That's how the recursive method that yields the *last node* might look like:

```
    public IntNode getLast(IntNode curNode) {
        if (curNode == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (curNode.next == null) {
            return curNode;
        }

        return curNode.next;
    }
```

Note, that `getLast()` can return a `null`. That means that field `first` is `null` and we can delegate to job to the method `addFirst()`. Otherwise, the new instance of the node will be created and assigned to `last.next`.

```
    public void addLast(int x) {
        IntNode last = getLast(first);
        if (last == null) {
            addFirst(x);
        } else {
            last.next = new IntNode(x, null);
        }
    }
```